# Adding JFreeChart wrapper chart to Vaadin project - declarative format container available?

Tags: html, vaadin, jfreechart, navigator

I'm definitely quite new to Vaadin (or similar frameworks) and I'm currently having great difficulties understanding how to include a chart (created using the Vaadin wrapper for JFreeChart) to the html file, which defines one of my views in Vaadin Navigator. I've followed this [tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/jfreechart-wrapper-for-vaadin/source/browse/trunk/jfreechartwrapper/src/test/java/org/vaadin/addon/JFreeChartWithVaadin.java?r=3) to create a Vaadin-compatible chart using JFreeChart and it's wrapper for Vaadin -  JFreeChartWrapper. I seem unable to find an element in [Vaadin's declarative format](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/declarative-ui) (you can test it [here](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#foundation/declarative-syntax)) that can make it possible for me to do that. My view for now is pretty simple and it includes a label and an embedded element (an image):

```
<v-vertical-layout size-full>
    <v-label _id="watching" size-auto :middle :center/>
    <v-embedded _id="pic" :middle :center :expand/>
    <!-- add chart element here! (_id="chart") -->
</v-vertical-layout>
```

Is there some generic container for charts and if not, how can I add one? For my Navigator stuff I have adapted the [AnimalViewer example](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.navigator.html) in Vaadin's book.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Vaadin book](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.declarative.html#application.declarative.elements.prefix) you can define a prefix for you component so you can use it in the HTML file. Suppose your class where you're using the vaadin addon/wrapper is `com.example.chart.MyChart` the following should be a working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- define c as prefix for package com.example.chart -->
    <meta name="package-mapping" content="c:com.example.chart"/>
</head>
<body>
<v-vertical-layout size-full>
    <v-label _id="watching" size-auto :middle :center/>
    <v-embedded _id="pic" :middle :center :expand/>

    <!-- use MyChart -->
    <c-my-chart _id="chart"/>
</v-vertical-layout>
</body>
</html>
```